# Retrieve data from mysql different tables and different IDs with Different Columns

Tags: mysql

I have those three tables...

```
   currency (Currency), 
   purchasingqty (PurchasingID, Rate, Qty)
   salesqty (SalesID, Rate, Qty)
```

I need to retrieve records from those 3 tables, without duplicates, in only one query. But this one returns duplicates.

```
SELECT
          currency.Currency,
          purchASingqty.PurchASingID,
          IFNULL(purchASingqty.Rate,0) AS Pur_Rate,
          SUM(IFNULL(purchASingqty.Qty,0)) AS Pur_Qty,
          salesqty.SalesID,
          IFNULL(salesqty.Rate,0) AS Sales_Rate,
          SUM(IFNULL(salesqty.Qty,0)) AS Sales_Qty
FROM     currency
LEFT JOIN salesqty ON currency.Currency = salesqty.Currency
LEFT JOIN purchASingqty ON currency.Currency =  purchASingqty.Currency
GROUP BY
          purchASingqty.PurchASingID,
          salesqty.SalesID
```

Comment: Add sample input data and expected results.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: currency : USD100, Purchasing : Currency-USD100 Rate-145.00 Qty-10, USD100 Rate-145.00 Qty-20, Sales : Currency-USD100 Rate-150.00 Qty-08, USD100 Rate-147.00 Qty-08 Now I need to retrieve purchasing and sales with unique IDs

Comment: Please edit your question